# Getting a panel within a JLayeredPane to stretch in a BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, border-layout, jlayeredpane

I have the following basic arrangement:

```
+--- JFrame ---------------------------------------+
| +-- Panel --+ +-- JLayeredPane ----------------+ |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| |           | |                                | |
| +-----------+ +--------------------------------+ |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

The panel on the left is on the `WEST` side of the `JFrame`'s `BorderLayout`, and the `JLayeredPane` is in the `CENTER`. How can I get a panel on the `DEFAULT` layer of the JLayeredPane to stretch with the size of the JFrame?

I tried setting a BorderLayout on the JLayeredPane, but it fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
  at org.rc.vitruvius.Vitruvius.main(Vitruvius.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
  at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.java:426)
  at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1130)
  at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:231)
  at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:975)
```

I'm using `add(Component, LayerConstant)`, and I guess somehow that's incompatible with the border layout.

EDIT: Here's a small example to illustrate:

```
package sandbox;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JLayeredPaneProblem extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JLayeredPaneProblem main = new JLayeredPaneProblem();
    main.go();
  }
  
  public void go()
  {
    createMainUI();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  
  private void createMainUI()
  {
    JPanel leftPanel = getLeftPanel();
    Component middlePanel = getMiddlePanel(getOtherPanel());
    
    add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
  }
  
  private Component getMiddlePanel(JPanel wrappedPanel)
  {
    JLayeredPane middlePanel = new JLayeredPane();
    middlePanel.add(wrappedPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    return middlePanel;
  }
  
  private JPanel getOtherPanel()
  {
    JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(100,100);
    otherPanel.setSize(size);
    otherPanel.setPreferredSize(size);
    otherPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    return otherPanel;
  }
  
  private JPanel getLeftPanel()
  {
    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    innerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(innerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    String [] items = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    JComboBox<String> cbox = new JComboBox<>(items);
    innerPanel.add(button);
    innerPanel.add(cbox);
    
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.add(innerPanel);
    
    
    return leftPanel;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the panel in the middle (blue border to see where its borders are) doesn't expand; I might have expected the JLayeredPane to expand and therefore the panel in its default (and other?) layers to expand, but none of them seem to. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: The error message indicates that you are calling method [add(Component, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) but the second method argument is an `int` and not an `Object`. Maybe if you would [edit] your question and post a [mcve] I may be able to help you fix that. Or maybe you just need to change the `int` to an `Integer`?

Comment: The attempt of setting `BorderLayout` on the JLayeredPane was a stab in the dark; I'm hoping someone knows how it's supposed to be done, instead of just trying more-or-less random things to see if something looks like it works. I can spend some time extracting an example out of what is not at all minimal, but I'm not trying to avoid this error message, I'm trying to find out how this is supposed to be done. I've satisfied myself that setting BorderLayout on the JLayeredPane isn't it.

Comment: I want to add a Panel that will have a null layout and with which I'll do absolute positioning. If I dump the size and preferred size of the JLayeredPane, I get 38,61 and 1,1, respectively -- I don't know where 38,61 comes from. I'd like this middle area to be a panel on which the user can drag and drop images, so I'd like it to expand to fit the available space. That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting a BorderLayout on the JLayeredPane, but it fails with...:

Add the component normally and then set the layer:

```
  private Component getMiddlePanel(JPanel wrappedPanel)
  {
    JLayeredPane middlePanel = new JLayeredPane();
    //middlePanel.add(wrappedPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    middlePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
    middlePanel.add(wrappedPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    middlePanel.setLayer(wrappedPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    return middlePanel;
  }
```

Using this approach there is no need for the ComponentListener.

Comment: Certainly looks easier -- one more question, a slight add-on to the original: the whole point of having the layered pane was to allow dragging on the drag layer; the example program I have for that creates a "glass pane" JPanel and assigns it to the DRAG_LAYER of the layered pane while being dragged. But I wouldn't think I would assign both the middlePanel AND the glassPanel to the CENTER of the borderLayout panel, or do I? I need this glass panel to have the same size as the middle panel and to overlay it, how do I do that?

Comment: In your last question that I answered you asked for clarification. I updated my answer providing more information and never heard from you. In this question you got a working solution and didn't "accept" the answer. I then provided a solution which you say is easier and yet you still haven't "accepted" this answer. Instead, you just continue to ask another unrelated question. This is not 20 questions. Its one question per posting. If you have a NEW problem then create your "MRE" and post it in a new question.

Comment: By the way I have never used code like my answer before. I just read the JLayeredPane API to try to better understand how it works. That is where I saw the setLayer(...) method in the overview of how the layered pane works. Also, if you are dragging components around a panel, there is no need to use a JLayeredPanel and the drag layer. Just drag then around the panel.

Comment: I apologize if you've been at all offended; I didn't add another comment to the one on my/our last question because I didn't have anything else to say about it, and I'm told not to use comments for 'thanks'. I just hadn't quite gotten around to marking this answer yet; I don't regard my question as "completely unrelated", but it is a different question, so I will go handle it differently. I do appreciate all the work you put into Swing answers on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JLayeredPaneProblem extends JFrame
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static JPanel otherPanel;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JLayeredPaneProblem main = new JLayeredPaneProblem();
    main.getContentPane().addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
        
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("componentResized()");
            otherPanel.setPreferredSize(e.getComponent().getSize());
            otherPanel.setMaximumSize(e.getComponent().getSize());
            otherPanel.setSize(e.getComponent().getSize());
            otherPanel.revalidate();
            otherPanel.repaint();
        }
        
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
        
        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
    main.go();
  }
  
  public void go()
  {
    createMainUI();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  
  private void createMainUI()
  {
    JPanel leftPanel = getLeftPanel();
    Component middlePanel = getMiddlePanel(getOtherPanel());
    
    add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
  }
  
  private Component getMiddlePanel(JPanel wrappedPanel)
  {
    JLayeredPane middlePanel = new JLayeredPane();
    middlePanel.add(wrappedPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    return middlePanel;
  }
  
  private JPanel getOtherPanel()
  {
    otherPanel = new JPanel();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(100,100);
    otherPanel.setSize(size);
    otherPanel.setPreferredSize(size);
    otherPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    return otherPanel;
  }
  
  private JPanel getLeftPanel()
  {
    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
    innerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(innerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    String [] items = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    JComboBox<String> cbox = new JComboBox<>(items);
    innerPanel.add(button);
    innerPanel.add(cbox);
    
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.add(innerPanel);
    
    return leftPanel;
  }
}
```

It appears that `JLayeredPane` takes into consideration the different sizes of its contained components. Hence you need to dynamically change those sizes in response to changes in the size of the top level `JFrame`.

In order to know when the top level `JFrame` is resized, I added a `ComponentListener` to the content pane of the `JFrame` and whenever the content pane size changes, I set the `otherPanel` size(s) to match the new size of the content pane.

Comment: So, you're getting the content pane of the main window and setting the size of the panel in the JLayeredPane to that. But what we really want is to set the size to the dimensions of the center portion of the main window, not its entire size. If you put `, 3` after the  `Color.blue` in the call that creates and sets the border, you can see that the right-hand edge of the panel does not show the border; I think that's because the window is actually now too big. Is there a good way to get the middle section dimensions on resize?

Comment: I just tried creating a default `JPanel` to put in the middle of the JFrame, then put the JLayeredPane in that panel and kept other things the same. I hoped that resizing that new JPanel would let me set new dimensions for the `otherPanel`; the `componentResized()` method for it is indeed called, and executes the same code that you wrote, but no border shows up. I don't know where the `otherPanel` went.

Comment: If I understand the problem, the ComponentListener should be added to the layered pane, not the content pane. I just moved the ComponentListener logic to the getMiddlePanel() method so the listener can be added to the layered pane.

Comment: Ok, that solved the problem of the border not showing up -- I changed the component listener to the middle panel, eliminated the extra panel I was trying, and now the border shows up on all 4 sides, indicating that the resized panel fills the center of the border layout as I wanted. So the resize event goes to the JLayeredPane, which we then write code for to resize the panel it contains? The code does `getSize()` from the JLayeredPane, which is in fact expanding with the JFrame. I wish I knew how I could have told that it would do that; I knew a panel would, but not a JLayeredPane.

Comment: @arcy A JLayeredPane is a component just like a JPanel or a JButton. Any component added to the "CENTER" of a BorderLayout will automatically be resized.